# How do I remove a nil key from my hash?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, null, key

With Ruby 2.4, I want to count the number of occurrences of an element and store them in a hash.  However, I don't want to include any nil keys in my hash.  So I tried

```
my_hash = int_data_col.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |i, h| h[i]+=1 }.delete(nil)
```

but this returns "1".  If I leave off the "delete(nil)", it returns a hash, but then a nil key is included in the hash (assuming a nil was present in the "int_data_col" array).  How do I remove the nil key from my hash and still get the correct results?

Comment: How would you be getting nil keys? This sounds like an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)" where you should ask about the generation of the hash, not how to clean it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array#compact`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-compact) which removes all `nil` values before the count.

```
my_hash = int_data_col.compact.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |i, h| h[i]+=1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 2.4, there's a way to do it which is very readable:

```
arr.compact.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:size)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clean up the array prior to hashing it, then

```
int_data_col.compact! 
int_data_col.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|i, h| h[i]+=1 }
```

If you want to simply create the hash, ignoring nil, without disturbing the original array, then the following as suggested by @sagarpandya82

```
int_data_col.compact.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |i, h| h[i]+=1 }
```

When you had specified `.delete(nil)`, I think you were expecting it to return the hash with the nil key removed. But what it did was remove the nil key and returned the count value of the nil key (1). From the Hash Class doc, "Deletes the key-value pair and returns the value from hash whose key is equal to key."

Comment: This doesn't add anything to @sagarpandya82's answer. Why do you think Natalia would like to remove the `nil`'s from the array?